# SQL Dynamic join on EXECUTE table column

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

Not sure if this is ever going to be possible, but I'm trying to do a dynamic join on EXECUTE, but the execution string has to come from a table column.... i.e

```
select * 
from (
         select table1.theSql,table1.userid 
         from table1 
        ) as a
inner join (execute a.thesql) as b on a.userId=b.userid
```

Comment: execute a new string comprising the above interpolated with the string in theSql ?

Comment: Does your dynamic SQL always return a result set that has a userid? Is the userid in table1 unique or can you have multiple rows per userid?

Comment: yeh - the userid is available in both

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no, something like that (at least that simply) is not possible.

The longer answer is that the closest thing to what you are trying to do would be a cross apply.  Cross applies allow you to execute a function (or something that could be written as a database function) on each row.  One of the limitations of functions is that they cannot have any side effects (ie, updates, deletes, inserts).  Since executing arbitrary sql could have a side effect, you cannot use it in a function and therefore can't use it in an apply statement.

Is there a way to get around this?  Yes, but it isn't pretty.  You are going to have to go with a dynamic sql solution.  Here is something that might be a starting point. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0e241/17)

**Sample Schema**

```
create table jigger
(
    id int,
    sql varchar(500)
)

insert into jigger values (1, 'select * from otherStuff')
insert into jigger values (2, 'select * from otherStuff where jigger_id = 2')

create table otherStuff
(
    id int,
    jigger_id int,
    name varchar(10)
)

insert into otherStuff values (1, 1, 'thing 1')
insert into otherStuff values (2, 2, 'thing 2')
insert into otherStuff values (3, 3, 'thing 3')
```

**SQL that Executes the SQL in the tables**

```
declare @innerSql varchar(8000)

set @innerSql = stuff((select ' UNION ALL select ' + cast(j.id as varchar(500)) + ' as jiggerSourceId, * from (' + j.sql + ') isql' + cast(j.id as varchar(500))
                        from jigger j
                        for xml path ('')), 1, 11, '')

declare @sql varchar(8000)

set @sql = 'select * from jigger j inner join (' + @innerSql + ') x on x.jiggerSourceId = j.id'

exec (@sql)
```

Comment: looks interesting - tried to have a quick go at this put the for xml path ('')), 1, 11, '') seems to cause bad syntax?

Comment: Are you missing a parenthesis somewhere? Or the call to stuff? That part is meant to clear out the first UNION ALL you would get when mashing all that sql together.

Comment: Its erroring on escape chars - example : contact_record.Customer = 1&#x0D;
   &#x0D;